# Getting parent relationship

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find the best way to structure this. I want to avoid `if`-`else` statements and reduce the number of code lines.

```
def get_parent(relationships,GU)
  parent = []
  if relationships.class == Array
    relationships.each do |y|
      if y[:relationship_roles][:relationship_role][:to_role][:name] == type
        parent << y[:party][:party_id][:id]
      end
    end
  else
    if relationships[:relationship_roles][:relationship_role][:to_role][:name] == type
      parent << relationships[:party][:party_id][:id]
    end
  end
  return parent
end
```

Input:

```
:relationship=>{:name=>nil, :party=>{:party_id=>{:id=>"12344", 
:id_type=>"abc"}, :name=>"XYZ", :@active=>"true", :@type=>"Organization"}, 
:relationship_roles=>{:relationship_role=>{:to_role=>{:name=>"GU"}}}}
```

The input could be only one relationship or multiple ones, which is why I have the `if`/`else` loop.

Comment: You say you have a loop, but you have no loop.  You must mean something else.  If you had a loop, you would have `loop..do..end`.  What are you trying to get rid of?  Nested if statements?

Comment: No doubt the question is poorly worded, but closing it for this reason... The code is clearly messy, it's not that important how the OP tries to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- It would be debatable whether it's good practice to have arguments which may contain either single elements or collections.
- If you convert whatever you get to an array (using `Array`), there is no need to repeat code.
- Don't use `each` + `<<` (imperative), use `map` + `compact` (functional).

I'd write:

```
def get_parent(relationship_item_or_collection)
  Array(relationship_item_or_collection).map do |relationship|
    if relationship[:relationship_roles][:relationship_role][:to_role][:name] == type
      relationship[:party][:party_id][:id]
    end
  end.compact
end
```

Comment: I would say using `map`/`compact` here is questionable, `inject` could be a better alternative if it was not so slow (in R1.8 at least, comparing to `each`). Totally agree with `Array()`.

Comment: Victor, I agree that map+compact is space-inefficient and slower. However, changing the right abstraction for the job with an `inject` or `each` (which are lower in the abstraction layer, speciall `each`) would be a pity, wouldn't it? For me the real solution would be to have an efficient abstraction (a pity it's not in the core). So in my projects I always have `compact_map` available, either my own implementation or from Facets: https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/enumerable/compact_map.rb

Answer (score 0):

*disclaimer: my ruby knowledge is practically nonexistent so the code below might be completely rubbish ruby-wise.*

I see two code smells in this code: [duplicate code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DuplicatedCode) and [switch on type](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell).

To eliminate the duplicate code we can apply the extract method refactoring:

```
def get_parent_for_relationship(relationship, parent)
  if relationship[:relationship_roles][:relationship_role][:to_role][:name] == type
    parent << relationship[:party][:party_id][:id]
  end
end

def get_parent(relationships)
  parent = []
  if relationships.class == Array
    relationships.each do |y|
      get_parent_for_relationship(y, parent)
    end
  else
    get_parent_for_relationship(relationship, parent)  end
  return parent
end
```

To make the switch on type even more visible, we can extract another method:

```
def get_parent_for_relationship(relationship, parent)
  if relationship[:relationship_roles][:relationship_role][:to_role][:name] == type
    parent << relationship[:party][:party_id][:id]
  end
end

def get_parent_for_array_of_relationships(relationships, parent)
  relationships.each do |y|
    get_parent_for_relationship(y, parent)
  end
end

def get_parent(relationships)
  parent = []
  if relationships.class == Array
    get_parent_for_array_of_relationships(relationships, parent)
  else
    get_parent_for_relationship(relationship, parent)  end
  return parent
end
```

Where you go from here is largely dependent on the calling code. An extensive discussion on switch on type, including strategies on dealing with it if it is really a problem can be found [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell)